# TwinView doesn't start at startup

Tags: 11.04, xorg, kubuntu, twinview

I've recently installed Kubuntu 11.04 and it is running on my dual screen setup. I have Nvidia video card and TwinView is working perfectly after I switched to the nvidia driver, and I saved the settings to `xorg.conf` so the second screen would automatically be in use on start up .

When I boot, however, the settings in `xorg.conf` are not used. I've checked to see if the file is used on start up, and indeed if I add some invalid configuration the X server does not start. So the file is read, but it looks like X ignores the settings in it.

I haven't found anything regarding this online, and I believe that the settings in `xorg.conf` are correct.

Any ideas as to why the X server doesn't seem to be picking up the settings from `xorg.conf`?

Here is the contents of my `xorg.conf` file: http://pastebin.com/spt1LDpz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the screen section in  `xorg.conf` was overridden by another file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

I removed that file, Now TwinView starts on boot and works as intended.